# Linear Algerba - translation of space $V$ by a six-dimensional vector $b$

Tags: matrices

The task I have has 2 parts, I did the first one but now I'm struggling with the second one.

In the **first part**, I was supposed to find all $2\times3$ matrices $A$ that satisfy the equation: $A\times[1\;1\;1]^T=[0\;0]^T$. I did that, the $A$ matrices are in the form:
$$\begin{bmatrix}x&y&-x-y\\z&w&-z-w\end{bmatrix}$$

Then I was supposed to find the basis and dimension for the linear space $V$ that these matrices create, which I also did - dimension is $4$ and the basis is:

$$\{\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}-1&1&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\1&-1&0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\-1&0&1\end{bmatrix}\}$$

Now in the **second part**, I'm looking for all $B$ matrices that satisfy this equation: $B\times[1\;1\;1]^T=[6\;6]^T$ and I'm supposed to present the set of all the $B's$ as as a translation of the space $V$ by a six-dimensional vector $b$.

How would this vector b look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$b$ would look like $\begin{bmatrix}b_1&b_2&b_3\\b_4&b_5&b_6\end{bmatrix}$.  Or if you like $b=(b_1,\dots,b_6)$.

You need to find the $b_i$.  $b$ should be a particular solution of the second equation.

Comment: b would look something like this (I did the same thing as in the first part): $$\begin{bmatrix}x&y&6-x-y\\z&w&6-z-w\end{bmatrix}$$
so now to provide the answer do I just find one particular b, for example:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\5&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
and present the set of $B's$ as the translation of $V$ by vector $b$ so:

$$\alpha\times\begin{bmatrix}1&0&-1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}+\beta\times\begin{bmatrix}-1&1&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}+\gamma\times\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\1&-1&0\end{bmatrix}+\delta\times\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\-1&0&1\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\5&0&1\end{bmatrix}?$$

Comment: @agromek I believe so. That is, yes.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much:)

Comment: You're welcome.   Adding any element of the kernel to a particular solution gives another solution.